# Threads in main Windows Form throwing "Out of memory", why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

I'm getting an out of memory issue in my main form on Visual Studio and I don't know why, I need to put a progress bar while my program is initializing, it works fine with other forms of my program, but not in the main form, it throws me an out of memory error

Here is the main form code:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        checkinstance();

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();

        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                progressDialog.SetIndeterminate(true);                  
                InitializeComponent();
                progressDialog.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressDialog.Close()));
            }
        ));

        backgroundThread.Start();
        progressDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

ProgressDialog is a form with a progress bar,

Thanks.

Comment: What is `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to do anything with your UI on any thread (especially a background thread) other than the UI thread.  This code is very bad in a lot of different ways.

Comment: Wait... are you running `InitializeComponent()` on another thread? Remove that for a start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, i ended up using a BackGroundWorker and ProgressBar inside handlers, for those who can have the same problem these are great articles

http://mycodelog.com/2010/02/11/busy/

[http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar]

http://theraneman.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/did-you-wish-backgroundworker-had.html (specially here)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the initialization of your UI controls takes a lot of time. That's why you are putting `InitializeComponent` into the background thread.

However, that will fail miserably:
InitializeComponent creates the instances of your UI objects. UI objects are only allowed to be called from the UI thread. That is generally the thread they have been created on.
The consequence is that every code accessing your UI objects outside of your background thread will result in an exception.

You need to take a completely different approach here. You need to identify what exactly takes so long when starting up the main form and put *that* code in a background thread.